# XSLT 1.0 to strip whitespace

Tags: xml, xslt, code-formatting

I want an output xml file which has no empty spaces after removing the `guid` element.

1. Input XML-file which is formatted like this:

```html
  <FilterDefinition xmlns="com.cisag.sys.tools.bi.obj.FilterDefinition">
    <guid>72312782178912782380210</guid>
    <name>REI0101</name>
    <description>Partner</description>
    <object>com.cisag.app.general.obj.Partner</object>
    <nlsMode>SINGLE_LANGUAGE</nlsMode>
    <dateTimeMode>COMPACT</dateTimeMode>
    <exportTransformationURI/>
    <importTransformationURI/>
    <logLevel>USER</logLevel>
    <logFolder/>
    <authorizationMode>NO_CHECK</authorizationMode>
    <filter>677869876769097980</filter>
  </FilterDefinition>
```

2. Now I'm matching the element `guid` like this:

```html
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$FilterNode/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="guid"></xsl:template>
```

3. Output is like this. Instead of the `guid` element, there is now a blank line which I don't want:

```html
  <FilterDefinition xmlns="com.cisag.sys.tools.bi.obj.FilterDefinition">

    <name>REI0101</name>
    <description>Partner</description>
    <object>com.cisag.app.general.obj.Partner</object>
    <nlsMode>SINGLE_LANGUAGE</nlsMode>
    <dateTimeMode>COMPACT</dateTimeMode>
    <exportTransformationURI/>
    <importTransformationURI/>
    <logLevel>USER</logLevel>
    <logFolder/>
    <authorizationMode>NO_CHECK</authorizationMode>    
    <filter>677869876769097980</filter>
  </FilterDefinition>
```

4. Desired result:

```html
  <FilterDefinition xmlns="com.cisag.sys.tools.bi.obj.FilterDefinition">
    <name>REI0101</name>
    <description>Partner</description>
    <object>com.cisag.app.general.obj.Partner</object>
    <nlsMode>SINGLE_LANGUAGE</nlsMode>
    <dateTimeMode>COMPACT</dateTimeMode>
    <exportTransformationURI/>
    <importTransformationURI/>
    <logLevel>USER</logLevel>
    <logFolder/>
    <authorizationMode>NO_CHECK</authorizationMode>    
    <filter>677869876769097980</filter>
  </FilterDefinition>
```

I think I have to also match formatting characters to get my desired result.

Comment: use strip space to avoid blank enter: `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`

Comment: You would probably also need `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />` too.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the comments from @AmrendraKumar and @TimC as an answer: Use `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` when processing data-oriented XML like this, in which the whitespace between elements has no significance. Then use `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` to inject new whitespace into the output, to achieve the desired layout (or something close to it).